# Is there an Java API viewer on command line like man for c and ri for ruby?

Tags: java, linux, bash, documentation

Is there an Java API viewer on command line?

I have been using `man` for C programming and `ri` for Ruby programming. Both of them seems very convenient for me, and now I am looking for something alike for Java API.

I apologize if this question has been raised before. I did many Google searches but no result shows up. I think I might have been using the wrong terms.

Comment: For productivity most Java developers use an IDE there are a number of excellent, free IDEs such as netbeans, eclipse or IntelliJ CE.  These allow you to navigate to source and documentation from the code.  I wouldn't use the command line unless you like doing things the hard way.

Comment: If you really want command line, I guess you can always use Lynx to view http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/ :)  But your best bet is really to make sure you've integrated the JavaDoc into your favorite IDE (like Eclipse or NetBeans).

Comment: Technically you could launch your web browser from the command line ...

Comment: Thanks... I guess I'll just get use to eclipse...

Answer (score 14):

As part of the JDK, you will also receive the javap utility that allows you to see method signatures in a java .class file.

```
javap myClass
```

For java API, you can use

```
javap java.lang.Integer
```

If you are a vi fanatic, use this tweak to see the method signature on the class under cursor with the following addition to your ~/.vimrc.

```
let $jre='/cygdrive/c/jdk1.6.0_21/jre'  
map tt yy:tabnew ^R^W^M  
map + tt:set ft=java^M!!javap -public `grep .*%$ $jre/lib/classlist`^M
```

1. Characters preceeded by caret like ^M need to be typed using Ctrl+V then Ctrl+M
2. javap needs to be in your system path
3. Use your own jre location in place of this
4. Finally, since this is tested using cygwin, you may need to do some touch ups

Another way is to use a text-based browser. See: 
[Look up javadoc Help file from Vim [Unix Only]](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=801)

Comment: FYI its caret, not carrot :-)

Comment: @saalehr Can this answer be updated for Java 11 and beyond? There is no longer a jre folder, but javap can be accessed directly. I'm not too well versed on the vim stuff, so can someone update it?